# intel_backlight directory does not exist in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, brightness, backlight

Previously I'd been changing my laptop screen brightness by directly changing the value of `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`; But recently I noticed that `intel_backlight` directory is disappeared, and I can't change the screen brightness.

There has been another directory named `ideapad` in `backlight` directory which contains files and directories listed bellow:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 10 09:57 actual_brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 10 10:05 bl_power
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 10 10:05 brightness
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 10 10:05 device -> ../../../VPC2004:00
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 10 09:57 max_brightness
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Aug 10 10:05 power
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 10 10:05 scale
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 10 09:57 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/backlight
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 10 09:57 type
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 10 09:57 uevent
```

I tried changing `ideapad/brightness`, but it didn't effect on screen brightness.

Now, How can I change my screen brightness, Or how can I bring `intel_backlight` back?

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solutions suggested in other posts and forums, but none of them worked.

My ubuntu grub was updated, by running ubuntu with previous grub, the `intel_backlight/brightness` came back.

In my case, I had to come back to `grub 5.19.0`.
You can find out [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1393019/1563170) how to change your running grub version.